# .NET 4.0 Page.Response.Write vs <%= %>

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, response.write

I have some UserControls in a webpage. When I use it in the ASPX code of my UserControl 
as such `<div><% Page.Response.Write("<a href='http://www.microsoft.com'>test</a>") %></div>`, my anchor is rendered at the start of the page:

```
<a href='http://www.microsoft.com'>test</a><html><head>
```

**instead of the expected:**

```
<html><head /><body>
<a href='http://www.microsoft.com'>test</a></body></html>
```

But if i use `<div><%="<a href='http://www.microsoft.com'>test</a>" %></div>` then the response is written inline as expected.

We used this technique of `Page.Response.Write()` a lot in .NET 3.5, and now migrating to .NET 4.0, we are experiencing this problem with it. Why does it happen in .NET 4.0?

Comment: Just an additional note, I think the word you want is *experience*, instead of *experiment*.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the code some more? A simple test of this isn't producing similar results. Are you dynamically creating these controls? When are they being added to the page?

Answer (score 2):

I would move to using the `Literal` control.

Comment: But my real questions is why it's now appened in .net 4.0 ?